# Airflow - backend database to get reports

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get some useful information from airflow backend. I need to get following details

1. How many times a particular job failed.
2. which task has failed over and over.

The problem is all our task has dependency on their upstream, and so when it fails, we fix the issue and mark it as success. This changes status in database as well. Is there a place I can get historical records?

following query shows which task failed. However if I mark it as success from UI, status is updated in database as well. And I have no way to show if this was failed.

```
select * from dag_run where dag_id='test_spark'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no native way but you can check `log` table -- it adds a record whenever there is action via CLI or UI.